# How do i insert a blank line before every comment (eg "#") in VIM?

Tags: vim

Hi In Gvim I need to insert a blank line or two before every comment in the file.

Eg

```
#comment 1
#comment 2
statement 1
statement 2
#comment 3
```

After running the comamnd it should be

```
#comment 1

#comment 2
statement 1
statement 2  

#comment 3
```

How do i do this?

Thanks

Update: Thanks for the answers

But if the comments are continuous, i do not want newline to be added in between them. Is there a way to do this?

eg

```
#comment 1
#comment 2
```

I dont to want it to be

```
#comment 1

#comment 2
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also use this command: `:g/^#/norm O`

Ok, here is an explanation:

This is a shortcut of `:global/^#/normal O` which means:

- for each line starting with '#' (`:global/^#/`)
- do 'O' command in 'normal mode' (`normal O`) – which means to do what a 'O' key does in the 'normal' (not insert and not :command) VIM mode. And 'O' inserts a new line.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far since it's the most intuitive, but maybe you should explain how and why it works.

Comment: `:g[lobal]` trumps `:s[ubstitute]` +1 for you sir

Comment: This is all I needed, but doesn't actually answer the question, which doesn't want to double space block comments.

Answer (score 2):

there's a solution, which works in the "unimproved vi" as well:

:2,$g/^[ TAB]*#/s/^/^M/

where TAB and ^M must be entered as the corresponding control character.

Hope this helps - and my thanks go to Heikki for pointing on the 1st line problem

Answer (score 1):

**Not affecting the first line**

The example output looks like there should be no newline before the first line in the file.
You can add a **lookbehind** check to achieve that.

`:%s/^\n\@<=\ze\s*#/\r/`

`\n\@<=` Matches only if there's a newline before the current position, so the first line won't match. For more information see `:h \@<=`

That can also be done with a **line check**. The following regex matches only those lines that are not the first line.

`:%s/^\%>1l\ze\s*#/\r/`

`\%>1` Matches below line 1. See `:h \%>l`

---

Here's something that should work with the updated question, that is, only add a newline before the current line, if there is **no comment line before**.

`:g/^\%^\@<!\(^\s*#.*\n\)\@<!\s*#/norm O`

`^\%^\@<!` Do not match this line if the beginning of the file is before it. `:h \%^` and :h `\@<!`

`\(^\s*#.*\n\)\@<!` Only match this line if the first non-blank character on the previous line is not #.

This regex will change

```
#comment 1
#comment 2
statement 1
statement 2
#comment 3
```

to

```
#comment 1
#comment 2
statement 1
statement 2

#comment 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command: `:%s/^\ze\s*#/\r/`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way (works for 1st line too)

```
:s/^[ TAB]*#-1s/^/\r/
```